# #include <SFML/Network.hpp> not found

Tags: networking, c++, programming, sockets

Can someone help me out with this error. Trying to program a network scanner

```
cppns.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SFML/Network.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Network.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: For close voters. My preliminary opinion was considering this as off-topic. But in case that Ubuntu repository have these headers, I think it is on-topic. But question may be more detailed …

Comment: @N0rbert the Ubuntu repository has hundreds if not thousands of libraries. That doesn't make generic programming questions ontopic.

Comment: It should also be noted that this question has an accepted answer, so it is not conjectural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [development package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=SFML%2FNetwork.hpp) for this header:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```